# Task pool thread preventing UI shutting down when initialising performance counter

Tags: .net, wpf, system.reactive

I have a 'diagnostics' service which is using Reactive Extensions to observe values being produced from a couple of performance counters. It uses an `Observable.Create` with the subscription scheduled onto the task pool.

In general this work perfectly fine, but there is a scenario where the creation of the `PerformanceCounter` classes prevents the UI process from exiting correctly and keeps the executable hanging around in memory (observed in task manager).

This happens when the user closes the app whilst the PerformanceCounter instances are being created - a small race condition.

Ususally the creation of `PerformanceCounter` instance is pretty instantaneuos but if the instance of the PerformanceCounter was not disposed last time there is a potential the creation could take more than a couple of seconds, during this time window if the user closes the app the process will hang on closing closed.

The dispose method of the service is being called when the application exits, so the 'disposable' is shutting down any subscribers to the Rx stream.

**Any ideas how I can guarantee the task pool thread will exit if it's blocked trying to create the PerformanceCounter?**

Shown below is the constructor & dispose methods:

```
public DiagnosticsService(IIdleService idleService, IRxSchedulerService rxSchedulerService)
{
    _rxSchedulerService = rxSchedulerService;
    _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    _disposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    _bufferedInactiveObservable = Observable.Create<Counters>(x =>
    {
        var disposable = new CompositeDisposable();
        try
        {
            var processName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;

            var workingSetCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Working Set - Private", processName);
            workingSetCounter.NextValue();
            disposable.Add(workingSetCounter);

            var cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", processName);
            cpuCounter.NextValue();
            disposable.Add(cpuCounter);

            x.OnNext(new Counters(workingSetCounter, cpuCounter));
        }
        catch (Exception exn)
        {
            x.OnError(exn);
        }

        return disposable;
    })
    .SubscribeOn(rxSchedulerService.TaskPool)
    .ObserveOn(rxSchedulerService.Dispatcher)
    .CombineLatest(idleService.BufferedIdling(IdleBuffer), (x, y) => x)
    .Publish();

    _disposable = _bufferedInactiveObservable.Connect();
}

public void Dispose()
{
    _disposable.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

subclass the `TaskPoolScheduler` Rx scheduler and in your subclass when you override the method to run the action on a Task, create the Task with the `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` flag.  Actions scheduled on this scheduler will get dedicated threads that have the `IsBackground` property set to true, preventing them from blocking the application exit.

Comment: Why subclass the `TaskPoolScheduler` - its threads are background threads anyway? Also, he's already using the task pool and this isn't a case that needs a long running thread.

Comment: It didn't help, I even tried NewThreadScheduler and set the IsBackground property to True when the Observable.Create is called and still doesn't shutdown...

Answer (score 0):

If your code is hanging in unmanaged code - which I suspect may be the case here - running on a background thread, which all task pool threads are, may not help speed up the shutdown process.

Whilst I don't have intimate knowledge of the unmanaged resources associated with *reading* performance counters, I think it's all unmanaged memory. So I am fairly certain that, in this case NOT disposing the counters in the event of application shutdown wouldn't causes any mess that would survive process termination.

Whilst it feels a bit "dirty", I think that in this case you could have a special case that doesn't dispose the performance counters on application shutdown. Maybe you could check a static flag you set to indicate you are shutting down, and not call `Dispose()` in that case? You may also need to call `GC.SuppressFinalize()` on the performance counters when shutting down as well.

Comment: I believe under the covers performance counters use some kind of shared memory (file) and if you don't unsubscribe there can be an issue with registering  - it takes longer than expected.

Comment: I also tried putting in a finalizer and preventing dispose on termination - still the same problem.

Comment: Hmmm... when you put "I also tried putting in a finalizer"... was that a typo? Did you mean you tried putting in a `SuppressFinalize` call? A finalizer is what we are trying to avoid. Either way, if that's not helping, then I'm stuck for now. :) Not really an Rx problem at that point I guess. Can you prevent the user from shutting down whilst performance counters are being created?

Comment: yes, a typo, I tried suppressing on the perf counter instances, preventing the user shutting down whilst they are initialising seems the only option at the moment, but it feels like a hack, thanks for the help

Comment: AwkwardCoding? :) Couldn't resist... interested to hear if you find a fix.